# Homological orientation of a manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

I'm trying to prove (without results) that if $M$ is an orientable topological manifold then every open set of $M$ is orientable.
 I'm assuming as definition of orientation the **reformulation 3**  of [orientation](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Orientation_of_manifolds).

Comment: Hint: Local homology has its name because $H_n(M,M \setminus x) = H_n(U, U \setminus x)$ for any neighborhood of $U$ of $x$. Here I write equality for the natural isomorphism induced by excising $U^c$.

Comment: Yes, in this way I have a generator $M_x\in H_n(U,U\setminus x)$, but how I can check that the choice is continuos?

Comment: The *collection* of generators was continuous to begin with. First try showing that you can shrink the neighborhood in the definition of continuity, since you will need a neighborhood in $U$ ($U$ in earlier comment, not the $U$ on the linked page.)